# How to response dynamic content in Nodejs without Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

```
      let reqBody = "";
      req
        .on("data", (chunk) => {
          reqBody += chunk.toString();
        })
        .on("end", () => {
        const body = new URLSearchParams(reqBody);
        res.end("ok");
        });
```

I'm trying to access the request's body using NodeJS without Express but for some reason, I could not run `res.end("ok");`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call `req.end()` as well

check Node.js document
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

> With http.request() one must always call req.end() to signify the end
> of the request - even if there is no data being written to the request
> body

```
 let reqBody = "";
  req
    .on("data", (chunk) => {
      reqBody += chunk.toString();
    })
    .on("end", () => {
    const body = new URLSearchParams(reqBody);
    res.end("ok");
    });
   req.end();
```

Comment: Uh, the line you've quoted is for *making requests* with `http.request`, not for receiving requests to a http server that you could respond to like the OP attempts?

Comment: Yes, and the quoted code is also for making requests